# how to parse a url with json options in it?

Tags: json, curl, uri

Like the title says, I'm trying to parse a url like the following:

```
https://salzundbrot.com/suche/#!search={"s1":60,"s2":90,"r1":2,"r2":4,"f1":450,"f2":750,"c":3}&x=1&view=infotiles
```

curl throws the following error:

```
$ curl https://salzundbrot.com/suche/#!search={"s1":60,"s2":90,"r1":2,"r2":4,"f1":450,"f2":750,"c":3}&x=1&view=infotiles
-bash: !search={/"s1/": event not found
```

ruby's uri module can't handle it either, throwing a `bad URI(is not URI?)` error.

Single quotes don't work, escaping the double quotes doesn't work (same errors) - surely there's a way to do this, but I can't find it.

Comment: You're not going to get the results you're expecting with this kind of URL. The part of the URL beginning with `#` (the "hash" or "fragment identifier") will not be sent to the server by curl—it will only request `https://somesite.com/search/`. Per [RFC-3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5), "the fragment identifier is separated from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced solely by the user agent."

Comment: fair enough - thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented above, you're not going to get the results you're expecting with a URL that has data in the "hash" or "fragment identifier", i.e. the part after `#`, because that part of the URL is not sent to the server by curl (or web browsers). Given a URL like `http://example.com/#!foo=bar`, curl will only request `http://example.com/`. Per RFC-3986, "the fragment identifier is separated from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced solely by the user agent."

However, for other URLs, you can use a HEREDOC with `xargs`. Curl's `--globoff` option prevents it from interpreting brackets or curly braces (otherwise `foo{bar,baz}` will make curl make two requests, one for `foobar` and one for `foobaz`).

```
$ xargs <<END curl --globoff
https://somesite.com/search/?search={"s1":55,"s2":90,"r1":2,"r2":4,"f1":450,"f2":775,"c":3}&x=1
END
```

Comment: that 'works' in that it returns something, but only gibberish.  i'll put the url i'm actually using so you can see for yourself

Comment: I had forgotten about curl's behavior with braces. I've updated my answer.